# looking to extend wifi range

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I currently have a trendnet ac1750 router it sits in one end of the house. Would it be best to get another one for elsewhere im the house or use a access point?

Is there a product that works better with this router?

Answer (score 2):

You have different options, some easy, some not. Depends on what you want, what you have and any experience...

1. Buy a dedicated wifi extender. A simple device you plug into a wall socket and it repeats your wireless signal. Cheap + easy to setup
2. An access point. Exactly what it says on the tin. Brings wifi to a non-wifi network. Needs an ethernet cable to connect it to your router/switch. Can be expensive but fairly easy to configure.
3. A wireless router in "bridge" or "access point" mode. The hardest to configure but you can re-use an old router if it can be set in the required mode. Cheap but why go and buy another router? Needs an ethernet cable to plug into your existing router. Needs to be configured.

The easiest method? 1 - a "plug-in" range extender. From about £30.

Comment: Another option is a powerline network adapter.  It uses the house wiring so you can access a network connection any place you have an electrical outlet, and there aren't issues of signal obstruction or range.

Comment: Plus that! ;) Thanks fixer1234. The problem with powerline network devices are they need to be installed on the same circuit in the property and if it's wifi you're looking at extending you'll still need an AP or router in AP mode ;)

Comment: @BigChris thanks for the reply. Do any of the options require that you use a different wifi network ie I need to use xyz network when on one end of the house and on the other I need to use zyx with no continuous wifi flow? Or am I wrong in the above?

Comment: @Tony - if you configure them all correctly then, no, they should all work seamlessly when you move between the points.